Why does the Apple II have the VERIFY command in DOS 3.3 and ProDOS?
On the Apple II, DOS 3.3 and the later ProDOS environments included a VERIFY command which allowed you to "verify that the file was readable". If you provided a filename to the command at a DOS prompt, it would either "read" the entire contents of the file and then exit silently or report a "file not found" or "I/O error". Though the file would be "read", it would not load the contents into memory nor would it replace your existing BASIC program.
I've always wondered why this command existed. Yes, it is an easy way to figure out if a file exists, but unless the file is one sector the overhead of reading a file could be excessive. And of course, it can tell you if a disk is corrupted but seeing how there were few (if any) means to repair a corrupted disk, it could be argued as somewhat useless.
So any thoughts as to why the VERIFY command existed? Given its limited utility, perhaps it was just very few lines of code to implement (i.e. do the READ operation but never copy DOS buffer to RAM) and was an easy feature?

how is it useless to know you've lost data prior to trying to use said data? Wrong data is usually worse than no data.

You typically really want to know which files are affected by bad media.

That seems like a very useful command to me, particularly if you want to verify backups before formatting a hard drive or verify a copy of programs or data before sending it somewhere for use in another computer. Often even better is a comparison (byte-by-byte match), but that only works if you have the original on another disk, or a CRC or other way of mathematically verifying that the file has not changed (from an either a copy or from itself previously read). But even a simple VERIFY makes a lot of sense in a lot of situations.

I think part of it is second-system effect. It was pretty routine to have problems saving files to cassettes, so people asked for a command to verify them. But they'd have had to pay Microsoft for a rewrite, and get a new spin of the Applesoft ROM, which was expensive. So when they wrote DOS, they included it, even though disks made it rather less necessary/useful.

There is, apparently, a slight difference between DOS 3.3 VERIFY which checks if the file is fully readable, and ProDOS, which only checks if the file exists.

I think my "somewhat useless" statement comes from the idea that I don't recall ever having media issues BITD and I think (Pro)DOS did a good job of catching I/O errors at save-time. But perhaps I was just lucky :-)

When you're trying to diagnose why something isn't behaving as expected, verifying that there is corruption is very much not useless. You know right then to end the mystery and frustration and look no further. I/O errors can develop between save time and some time later when you want to read again.


Why does the Apple II have the VERIFY command in DOS 3.3 and ProDOS?

Why not? Beside anyone may have a different opinion here, I would think it being quite useful to

check if a file

exists at all,
on the desired dive,
in a specific slot,
with the right volume mounted,


see if a file saved is done so in a readable fashion or
see if a file is readable in its entire length before processing.

It's about the same reasoning why PC-DOS has CHKDSK <file> and VERIFY commands. Given, Apple's DOS is less sophisticated, still the basically same idea.
Next thing is simplicity. Such a routine isn't a big deal and may have been used internally as well.
Last but not least, don't underestimate how bad diskettes were early on, especially the lowest priced ones hobbyists could afford. Nor how much abuse diskettes had to endure. So being able to check a file seems useful. Same way as cassette recording on may systems saved a program twice, just in case.


On the Apple II, DOS 3.3 and the later ProDOS environments

For ProDOS it's an obvious must to maintain compatibility.

included a VERIFY command which allowed you to "verify that the file was readable".

Plus all of the other parts (slot, drive, volume, name)

If you provided a filename to the command at a DOS prompt, it would either "read" the entire contents of the file and then exit silently or report a "file not found" or "I/O error".

Plus "VOLUME MISMATCH".

Though the file would be "read", it would not load the contents into memory nor would it replace your existing BASIC program.

Reading means to read the directory, read the track/sector list, follow it and read all sectors, which in turn check each sector (including directory and TSL) to exist with a valid and matching header, valid data and a matching checksum. All in all a good reporting of disk and data integrity for this file.

I've always wondered why this command existed. Yes, it is an easy way to figure out if a file exists, but unless the file is one sector the overhead of reading a file could be excessive.

One very nice way - especially it not only returns the file to be existing (on the drive specified with the right disk mounted), but also usable. Great thing to do when starting an application and opening files to know they are at least on file system level intact.

And of course, it can tell you if a disk is corrupted but seeing how there were few (if any) means to repair a corrupted disk, it could be argued as somewhat useless.

As mentioned, there may be different opinions. Often tied to use case. For someone just writing some code with most disk handling on the command line (aka SAVE/LOAD) it may be of less concern (*1). On the other hand, for serious usage, checking for valid setup and data before accessing those is a huge bonus with any serious application.

So any thoughts as to why the VERIFY command existed?

I always thought of it as a great way to check data and setup integrity at the start. One single line of BASIC code with direct handling of any exception may save a lot of error handling code spread out around the program.

Given its limited utility, perhaps it was just very few lines of code to implement (i.e. do the READ operation but never copy DOS buffer to RAM) and was an easy feature?

Which it of course is.
VERIFY execution itself, which is needed for SAVE/BSAVE a mere 19 bytes of code (*2).
Making VERIFY a command on its own needs the addition is

6 bytes for the command name
2 bytes for the keyword table entry
3 byte handler address
4 bytes command handler

A mere total of 15 additional bytes don't sound bloaty to me :))

In fact, the way it is implemented, VERIFY uses the file manager interface to carry over all parameters of SAVE/BSAVE, which in turn can spare all setup, except for the inserting the VERIFY command code ($0C). So not implementing VERIFY as a command would just save the command name entry (6 byes, #1 above) and 2 bytes of the handler (#4 above). I'd say spending 8 bytes for such a useful command is pretty sleek.

*1 - Not at least as VERIFY is automatically called at the end of every SAVE or BSAVE (*3).
*2 - $AD18-$AD2A in DOS 3.3 (Label FVAR)
*3 - Unless switched off patching DOS via POKE 46732,76

I suspected that SAVE/BSAVE used the VERIFY routine and perhaps why I never found a use for it; any time the media was bad during a save, DOS would let me know. Now I wonder how many applications did the same when saving (say) a word processor file?  Either way, you've validated that the implementation overhead was so few bytes why NOT make it a command? Thanks for the thorough answer.

1970s floppy disks weren't hugely reliable. 5.25" floppies expose part of the recording medium when they aren't in the drive, which makes them prone to collect dust. At the time, dust often included cigarette ash, which was widely spread around most workplaces in the 1970s and early 1980s.
I did a couple of years work programming on Apple IIs with floppy drives, and you'd expect a floppy to go bad once or twice a month. A command to verify that data was readable was useful to check backups, for data to be sent elsewhere, and for many other purposes.

I'm not sure floppy disks were ever reliable enough that this command wouldn't make sense.  And CDs were only a little better.

When I managed to talk my parents into paying for a used, smoke-stained, slightly battered and probably not ideally aligned 1541 floppy drive for my Commodore in 1986 to replace the snail's pace Datasette, I still had to buy the floppies myself. Being a teenager on a shoestring budget, I usually got the cheapest brand I could find here in Germany, Verbatim Verex. The VERIFY command of Commodore BASIC was a lifesaver - unlike the Apple II version it would actually compare RAM and disk contents and fail if there was any difference -, as sometimes up to five disks out of a package of ten would develop problems, especially when saving cracked games to them on a friend's computer (his floppy drive was in much better shape). And in 1990 I lost a large-ish (though not very good) text adventure game I had programmed on a TRS-80 in school because IIRC that system didn't have a good VERIFY command, the shared hard drive developed a fault, and I wasn't yet wise enough to never overwrite your last known-good copy.

Are you sure 1990?

@Polluks yes 1990. The school got PCs in early 1991 but in 1990 there were still TRS-80s. It was Bloomingdale High School  in southwest Michigan where I spent a year as an exchange student.

Apple DOS 3.3 and ProDOS use the following procedure to write a sector's worth of data to a floppy drive:

Wait for a sector header mark
Read the sector number
If it's the right track but wrong sector, go to step #1
If it's the wrong track, move the head and go back to step #1 or give up, depending upon what one has tried so far.
Switch on the write circuitry, output a sector's worth of data, and switch off the write circuitry

No part of this procedure ensures that the drive was able to write data to the disk.
I'd characterize the reliability of 5.25" media as better than what some horror stories would suggest, but nonetheless less than perfect.  If one wrote a file to disk, performing an immediate VERIFY would allow one to discover most of the things that might have gone wrong while writing it at a time when one would be able to avoid data loss if the file wasn't written correctly (e.g. by saving the file under a different name and/or to a different disk).
